# How do I access the querystring using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a querystring which looks like this `page3.html?redesigndata=value` which it appears if its redirected from **page1.html** and `page3.html?new=yes` or `no` when redirected from **page2.html**. Here is the code I'm using to find out what the querystring is and do some functions on **page3.html**

```
var locurl = window.location.search;
if (locurl.substring(0, 13) === '?redesigndata') {
  alert("redesign!");
} else if (locurl.substring(0, 4) === '?new') {
  visit = locurl.substring(5);
  alert("somthing!");
  if (visit === 'yes') {
     alert("first!");
  } else if (visit === 'no') {
    alert("again!");
  }
}
```

but I don't get any alerts when I try this script and I cant find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Have you tried running it through Firebug in FireFox or something similar?

Comment: I'm not going to put another answer, but I'm not seeing a problem with the script either... appears to work fine

Comment: alert(window.location.search); What do you get?

Comment: ran it through Safari, Chrome and Firefox. but didnt work then i thought lets clear history. and now it works! Im really new to website coding usually i just do designing. But why did that happen even after refreshing the page it didn't work until i cleared the history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this function

```
function getQueryString() {
  var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
      re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

  while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }

  return result;
}

// ...
var myParam = getQueryString()["myParam"];
```

Check like this

```
if(getQueryString()["redesigndata"] != "")
```

Comment: Should this not be a singleton and not fail if the field does not exist at all

Comment: This is the basic code, proper checks has to be done wherever needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. If the alerts never fire, it's because the conditions are never met. Once a query string is added to the URL that DOES match one of those you listed in your code, the alert does fire.

Also, beware you're (seemingly) creating global vars.

Answer (score 1):

The script works on my box. Please put this script inside script tags